# OOM-killer docker

Tags: docker, tomcat, java-11

I have a running web application inside a docker container based on docker image `tomcat-9.0.13-jre11`. The container received a kill message from the linux system.

The only information that I found is from `dmesg`:

```
kernel: C2 CompilerThre invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0xd0, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
kernel: C2 CompilerThre cpuset=XXXXXX mems_allowed=0
kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 127722 Comm: C2 CompilerThre Tainted: G               ------------ T 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64
Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process XYZ (Keep-Alive-Time) score xyzzy or sacrifice child
kernel: Killed process (java) total-vm:5318236kB, anon-rss:3018632kB, file-rss:22336kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Do you have any suggestion or method to collect more infos?

Comment: Your memory is set too low for your application. Either your memory is set to a ridiculously small amount or you have a memory leak

Answer (score 2):

You can easily update the default memory size with `docker update` command.

```
docker update --memory 1G memory-eater-application-container-name
```

Documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/
Possible duplicates:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54568489/8929392
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44533437/8929392

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the memory allocated to the container or the default memory is too less for the application to run hence the application sent a kill signal.

```
Error: Memory cgroup out of memory:
```